# One public IP and two web servers

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, router, port, forwarding

We have our IBM server (internal ip: 192.168.1.128) connected to internet via router (192.168.1.1).
I have forwarded the following port:
Port 80: internal IP 192.168.1.128 for incoming HTTP connections.
HTTP requests are handled by xampp. For ex:- People use 122.168.xxx.53/moodle to access moodle. (Moodle is a online training platform and 122.168.xxx.53 is out public IP).

BigBlueButton is a web based virtual classroom program.

Our bigbluebutton server runs on a virtual machine having a bridged network connection with the host IBM server. Meaning the VM behaves like a physical machine connected to our server. I have assigned an IP (192.168.1.127) to the VM, so when on local network if i type this in browser
192.168.1.127/bigbluebutton , I am presented with bbb demo meeting page.

Problem:
I already have forwarded port 80 on internal ip 192.168.1.128 for others to be able to access moodle. 192.168.1.127 also runs bbb on port 80. We cannot forward same port 80 on two internal IPs. We cannot run bbb on any port other than 80 since it is a web service. If i am to retract 80 from 192.168.1.128 and forward it on 192.168.1.127, others can access bbb but not moodle. We need both. In a nutshell, we have two web servers and only one public ip (122.168.xxx.53) and only one web server can go through that public ip so that outside world can access it. How do I get both of them accessible to outside world?

Things I've tried:
I tried to make our IBM server behave as a proxy between incoming requests and our bbb server by editing httpd.conf file of apache server software and adding the entry
ProxyPass /bigbluebutton/ 192.168.1.127
 Meaning that if someone is to access the url 122.168.xxx.53/bigbluebutton/ , data will be fetched from 192.168.1.127 and will be displayed to the visitor.
For example i access a certain bbb page like 122.168.xxx.53/bigbluebutton/index.html
This page will be fetched from 192.168.1.127/index.html and will be displayed to outside visitor.
I am successful in that much, but the problem is that suppose that index.html web page contains a link to certain image as 'images/bbb_logo.jpg' intended to be interpreted as 192.168.1.127/images/bbb_logo.jpg is in fact interpreted as 192.168.1.128/images/bbb_logo.jpg' since 122.168.xxx.53 is mapped to 192.168.1.128 because we forwarded port 80 on ....1.128 and not on ....1.127. At this point , in case of relative urls embedded in the page, our apache proxy fails.

Useful information:
IBM server runs windows server 2008 r2 with xampp software to handle http requests.
BBB Virtual machine runs ubuntu server edition with nginx as http server.

Comment: It merely sounds like you need to update your applications' "Base URL" value to take into consideration the new proxied URL structure. If you do that, the application should take care of generating correct links to its resources.

Comment: Hi, bigbluebutton is not an application designed by me. Moreover there are many pages inside of it and it is very complex task to update all the urls inside bbb from relative urls to absolute urls. On top of that, it runs inside a VM which has Ubuntu server edition with no GUI only text based console.

Comment: Well then run bbb at the root of your proxy and Moodle at /moodle/.

Comment: I did that. But then when i tried to access moodle by publicip/moodle the page said Welcome to nginx. It appears that setting root of proxy to bbb server routes ALL requests to the bbb server.

Comment: Then you had your proxy configured incorrectly.

Comment: That might be the case, can you please point me to a good guide for configuring apache proxy?

Comment: Post the exact configuration you tried, so it can be diagnosed and fixed here.